# how to render JSON nested object?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

```
{
  "Title": "Home Alone",
  "Year": "1990",
  "Rated": "PG",
  "Released": "16 Nov 1990",
  "Runtime": "103 min",
  "Genre": "Comedy, Family",
  "Director": "Chris Columbus",
  "Writer": "John Hughes",
  "Actors": "Macaulay Culkin, Joe Pesci, Daniel Stern, John Heard",
  "Plot": "An eight-year-old troublemaker must protect his house from a pair of burglars when he is accidentally left home alone by his family during Christmas vacation.",
  "Language": "English",
  "Country": "USA",
  "Awards": "Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 10 wins & 4 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzFkM2YwOTQtYzk2Mi00N2VlLWE3NTItN2YwNDg1YmY0ZDNmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [{
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.5/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "65%"
    },
    {}
  ],
  "Metascore": "63",
  "imdbRating": "7.5",
  "imdbVotes": "406,011",
  "imdbID": "tt0099785",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "05 Oct 1999",
  "BoxOffice": "N/A",
  "Production": "Twentieth Century Fox",
  "Website": "http://www.foxhome.com/homealone/index_frames.html",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

React

```
{
  movie.Ratings[1].Value
} <!-- doesn't work to show Rotten Tomatoes score 65% -->'


{
  movie.Title
} <!-- code works fine -->
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to render  Rotten Tomatoes score 65% on react app. but I'm getting an error. {movie.Ratings[1].Value} it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: It should work... are you sure the `movie.Ratings` is populated with an array as in the JSON you posted?

Comment: I would also say to check if it is some asynchronous problem, but you said `movie.Title` works fine :/ ... Try `console.log` to check the content of your `movie` variable.

Comment: Try something like this `{ movie.Ratings && movie.Ratings[1] && movie.Ratings[1].Value || 'not-available' }` It should show the value if `movie.Ratings[1]` exists otherwise it will show `not-available`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@syed-ahmed

When you try to access non-existig property in a object, it will return undefined. Thus, you have to make sure that property exists. We can use make use of [javascript operator &&](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) which basically evaluates from left to right, and then returns the value from the right-most variable.

See example code below for your reference:

```js
const movieWithRating = {
  Title: 'Home Alone',
  Year: '1990',
  Rated: 'PG',
  Released: '16 Nov 1990',
  Runtime: '103 min',
  Genre: 'Comedy, Family',
  Director: 'Chris Columbus',
  Writer: 'John Hughes',
  Actors: 'Macaulay Culkin, Joe Pesci, Daniel Stern, John Heard',
  Plot:
    'An eight-year-old troublemaker must protect his house from a pair of burglars when he is accidentally left home alone by his family during Christmas vacation.',
  Language: 'English',
  Country: 'USA',
  Awards: 'Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 10 wins & 4 nominations.',
  Poster:
    'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzFkM2YwOTQtYzk2Mi00N2VlLWE3NTItN2YwNDg1YmY0ZDNmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg',
  Ratings: [
    {
      Source: 'Internet Movie Database',
      Value: '7.5/10',
    },
    {
      Source: 'Rotten Tomatoes',
      Value: '65%',
    },
    {},
  ],
  Metascore: '63',
  imdbRating: '7.5',
  imdbVotes: '406,011',
  imdbID: 'tt0099785',
  Type: 'movie',
  DVD: '05 Oct 1999',
  BoxOffice: 'N/A',
  Production: 'Twentieth Century Fox',
  Website: 'http://www.foxhome.com/homealone/index_frames.html',
  Response: 'True',
};

const movieWithNoRating = {
  Title: 'Home Alone',
  Year: '1990',
  Rated: 'PG',
  Released: '16 Nov 1990',
  Runtime: '103 min'
};

// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
const hasValue = movieWithRating.Ratings && movieWithRating.Ratings[1] && movieWithRating.Ratings[1].Value || 'not-available';

// eslint-disable-next-line prettier/prettier
const notAvailable = movieWithNoRating.Ratings && movieWithNoRating.Ratings[1] && movieWithNoRating.Ratings[1].Value || 'not-available';


console.log(hasValue); // Output 65%

console.log(notAvailable); // Output not-available
```

If you think it helped you then do not forget to mark this as an answer.